# Matlab: Get list of ordered pairs

Tags: matlab

Let me explain with an example: If I give '4' as input, I want the pairs (1,2), (1,3), (1,4),(2,3),(2,4),(3,4) in a matrix like so:

```
1 2
1 3
1 4
2 3
2 4
3 4
```

Why do I need this? I will generate a random number from 1 to (n*(n-1)/2) and I want the corresponding pair. I figured I will generate the pair list first and then use the random number as an index. If there is a direct solution to this, then much better!

Edit: 
Actually I don't need all pairs, I need t random ordered pairs that don't repeat and first value < second value. There are 5000 lists each with n elements. So total pairs possible is tot = 5000 * n * (n-1)/2. If I generate t random integers from 1 to tot using randperm, can I translate it into a pair? I can get the list number by dividing by 5000. And if I mod with 5000, I will get pair index. I was trying to convert this pair index into a pair. Sorry for not explaining all this before. Hope I am clear.

Comment: Generating a lot of numbers to then pick one of them can work for small N, but will definitely give you headaces as N grows larger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first part of your question: You want combinations of `n=4` elements taken `k=2` at a time. There's a function for that, namely [`nchoosek`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nchoosek.html):

```
n = 4; %// number of elements
k = 2; %// how many to pick in each group
result = nchoosek(1:n, k);
```

---

For the second part: here's a direct way to generate all ordered pairs:

```
n = 4;
x = randi(n); %// uniformly distributed on {1,2,...,n}
y = randi(n-1);
y = y + (y>=x); %// uniformly distributed on {1,2,...,x-1,x+1,...,n}
pair = sort([x y]);
```

Comment: Note that this approach does require the creation of a vector of size N, of course that would only be a problem for (very) large N.

Comment: Please see edit to my question. I am going to use nchoosek right now. But if you have a better answer (keywords: non-repeating, ordered pairs) then please let me know.

Comment: @TyanTowers Use `randsample`, as suggested in Dennis' answer, to get `t` unique indices. Then use that as a row index into the result of `nchoosek`

Comment: @LuisMendo is there any difference between randsample and randperm like what I implemented? (see prev edit in question)

Comment: @TyanTowers `randsample` may be less efficient. To generate 3 unique numbers out of 10 numbers you need `x = randperm(10); x = x(1:3)`.  So you generate a large vector and then pick only three elements. But the result is the same

Comment: @TyanTowers Oh, yes. I forget that newer versions of Matlab let you do that

Answer (score 2):

If you want an efficient algorithm that also works for large N, this should do it (and be nicely according to the uniform distribution):

1. Generate x as a number from 1 to n-1
2. Generate y as a number from 1 to n-2

Your first number is n-1

If y < x, your second number is y, otherwise it is y+1

---

I am not sure about whether this is implemented as such, but I think you could achieve this in matlab via:

```
sort(randsample(4,2))
```

Comment: To get only ordered pairs: `sort(randsample(4,2))`

Comment: Thanks. Actually, my n is quite small, but I need to do this many times. There are about 5000 lists with 10 elements each. I want to randomly get some t ordered pairs from this which does not repeat and both elements are different.

Comment: I see that the `x` and the `y` will be uniformely distributed, but shouldn't the `(x,y)` be?

Comment: @mbschenkel I don't have proof of it, but I think the pairs will also be equally likely. A pair (x,y) needs you to draw an x first and then an y, or an y first and then an x. Each number is equally likely to be drawn, so therefore I think each resulting pair is also equally likely to occur.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin: Sine `y > x` the number of possible `y` per draw depends on `x`. Hence in the example given in the question `(3,4)` would be equally likely as ` (1,2), (1,3), (1,4)` together, which is not what I would call a uniform distribution.

Answer (score 0):

Since the number of elements per row and column are not constant but linearly in- resp. decreasing, drawing a random `x`  first followed by a random `y` will lead to uniformly distributed `x`, but non-uniformly distributed `(x | y)`! Since I think that this property is important, we need to be careful. I will first draw a single, uniform, random variable `i` and then map this continuous index  to `(x | y)` as follows:

```
x \ y   1   2   3   4
1           #1  #2  #3
2               #4  #5
3                   #6
```

i.e. (1 | 2) <-> #1, etc. This is certainly feasible. But because will result in a quadratic equation and some rounding, it is a bit cumbersome.
I'm suggesting to instead index the full "square" and skip the ones on the *wrong side of the diagonal*:

```
x \ y   1       2       3       4
1       (#1)    #2      #3      #4
2       (#5)    (#6)    #7      #8
3       (#9)    (#10)   (#11)   #12
```

And skip those in parenthesis whenever they are generated. Now the function mapping from index `i` to `(x | y)` is much simpler:

```
i = (x-1) * N + y

x = floor(i/N) + 1
y = i - (x-1)*N + 1
```

The drawback is, that we can never be quite sure that we have enough samples on the desired side of the diagonal, so we need to be prepared for this.
However, the probability for this is quite small.

```
N = 6 % maximal x and y
S = 10 % number of samples to draw

ind = [];
% This loop will most likely run only once, 
% but we can not be completely sure
while size(ind, 1) < S
    % (*)
    % In order to test uniformity of distribution, we can 
    % generate some repeating data instead of the next line:
    % i = ceil(N*N .* rand(3*S, 1)); 

    % We generate 3*S > S samples, because at least 50% will be removed
    i = randsample(N*N, min(N*N, 3*S)); 

    x = floor(i/N) + 1;
    y = i - x*N + N + 1;

    remove = (x >=  y);
    x(remove, :) = [];
    y(remove, :) = [];

    ind = [x y];
end    
ind = ind(1:S, :);

% verify:
test = accumarray(ind, ones(S,1))
```

This could result in

```
ind =
     2     6
     3     4
     1     4
     3     6
     5     6
     2     3
     1     6
     3     5
     4     6
     1     5   

test =
     0     0     0     1     1     1
     0     0     1     0     0     1
     0     0     0     1     1     1
     0     0     0     0     0     1
     0     0     0     0     0     1
```

And the uniformity test for `S = 10000`:

```
test =
     0   671   716   686   691   664
     0     0   644   650   667   664
     0     0     0   672   649   654
     0     0     0     0   667   655
     0     0     0     0     0   650
```